# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

Tags: ssl

Ubuntu 16.04 
getting ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) error in jenkins job while uploading files on production

In my .py file I have import httplib and urllib aslo
Jenkins job running on ubuntu 16.04 and Job production is cent os 7

I have the following 21 lines python code:-

```
import httplib
import urllib
import os
import base64
AN=os.getenv("ACCESSNAME")
AP=os.getenv("ACCESSKEY")
U= 'login=%s&password=%s'%( 'Uname' , 'passwd' )
R = {'Authorization':'Basic '+base64.b64encode('%s:%s'%('Uname' , 'passwd' ))}
serverid = '192.168.0.*'
portno = 443
check_path='/store/shared/united_states'
h1=httplib.HTTPSConnection(serverid,portno)
if serverid=='192.168.0.*':
    h1.request('GET',"%s?%s"%(urllib.quote(check_path),U), None,R )
    print "connection successfull"
else:
    print "using 2ndUname login"
    h1.request('GET',check_path+'?login=2ndUname&password=passwd',None,{})
r1 = h1.getresponse()
statuscode=r1.HTTPS_PORT
print statuscode
```

It works on Ubuntu 12.04 but not on Ubuntu 16.04
On Ubuntu 16.04 it gives an error "ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)"

Certificate details:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=IE/ST=Dublin/L=Dublin/O=Default Company Ltd
   i:/C=IE/ST=Dublin/L=Dublin/O=Default Company Ltd
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDFjCCAf4CCQCgG89C0FwA9zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBNMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJ
RTEPMA0GA1UECAwGRHVibGluMQ8wDQYDVQQHDAZEdWJsaW4xHDAaBgNVBAoME0Rl
ZmF1bHQgQ29tcGFueSBMdGQwHhcNMTgwMjEyMTYxNjU4WhcNMTkwMjEyMTYxNjU4
WjBNMQDVQQ1UECAwGRHVibGluMQ8wDQYDVQQHDAZEdWJswecffcerqwethhyrrre
aW4xHDAaBgNVBAoME0RlZmF1bHQgQ29tcGFueSBMdGQwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
AQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDp/GMnHTBzlVNIG/WjhLupxlWnQKL08AaYVo/6USav
jFcUFMupRuI4IMK2nuR4GUkQ6aYkqO8Vm83MokwVnSk+FVGs4mHkpcRwAuhQ61CD
vw9ZfSGJ3kaXbrcgZrtpjsNH5P3pne4/L73WI2fuQyDMVyoJFjbhQe/88qm/tXGS
qKxbdK/AtJkd/M1O7wd3GQzmklGTaabxP64Aut6zdq3ZUzs3r5yf5tsqre32rd2r
Uck3pUcmFW1MaYcwPbXNoOGFXWHWH+G8OliZd7y/y79MMW3YLrmzxxbcODccXih8
8mqMB8jd9UzOcI1XPCxgJ/VX6363yQqa1ih2oWNGqMEtAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcN
AQELBQADggEBAD32ABRkmFiVqg72XBsF0rq/BAhkjsgMZCyjrLdrYLMpkmPlvFbj
Qz6ZoXDuBup6+QrlekhAYHJPs0vVv/9yffHymBmX7nnYSiOdKt1e233rvyjg3234
76I3ZVp42hDqZpmlycQ6+sILOQYCh/9zgJMD8yXmptYk9AnM4T1fXacqbRUw760E
vUZJDNyE4l7hbsWlJ9cqio2ITHM4mSYGPtihDSyD6ZhO22ny4Xed2pzmVTwjUfbq
fg7pdhiv93gpc+W896b8oay6HGO9q0g1DsGt7RdINbnHk+srCcBinZpn+HEqFqBi
q6vCYoqH7NVMQ4/y6M3tvqb1xg2TOI9VWno=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=IE/ST=Dublin/L=Dublin/O=Default Company Ltd
issuer=/C=IE/ST=Dublin/L=Dublin/O=Default Company Ltd
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1485 bytes and written 431 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: A986151BD77C7B6BCC96E87C88C9463A794A3A9C34CA6AAE0B3012E5BCCC9053
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 5899F9E0C15D2CE071A8F6DBF36FD74F1137BA492A3D6383D7A0D5A36F46AB993CC5F740E87440C21B54ABCE3F7B6DC1
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - bd b6 8a 7d 9e ed 63 09-f4 93 4b e4 ad 4e e5 5c   ...}..c...K..N.\
    0010 - dd a9 69 2a ce 10 3c 81-df 14 b5 c1 2f 44 79 0c   ..i*..<...../Dy.
    0020 - 06 46 7d e4 c0 99 9c 23-32 6c b9 4b 85 b6 e6 6b   .F}....#2l.K...k
    0030 - 44 ae 14 44 6c 0a 22 4b-0f 25 24 80 d2 72 49 dd   D..Dl."K.%$..rI.
    0040 - 25 1f 07 91 f4 fe 40 3d-e6 1a 60 c3 30 83 88 71   %.....@=..`.0..q
    0050 - 05 dd a1 89 41 47 33 0d-8f 09 16 69 f1 bb 5a c7   ....AG3....i..Z.
    0060 - da 7a 5c e7 fb a5 53 f5-09 9c de 50 c3 de ac f7   .z\...S....P....
    0070 - 09 27 29 32 c3 d3 99 6a-d8 50 3c 06 a2 7a e5 ce   .')2...j.P<..z..
    0080 - 3b 77 12 7e 9f b6 c1 cb-42 ff a2 44 aa 89 a9 13   ;w.~....B..D....
    0090 - f6 b7 94 71 86 db ff af-6d 95 bb 3b 9e 0e 3f 4a   ...q....m..;..?J
    00a0 - 6c df 87 7a fc 9b 94 48-17 8b 24 db 9f 4c 84 e8   l..z...H..$..L..
    00b0 - b6 4c 11 6b be 55 84 8e-f8 0d 44 b4 6f b0 9f 81   .L.k.U....D.o...

    Start Time: 1553235005
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
---
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 22 Mar 2019 06:14:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Do you have valid server certificates?

Comment: I have newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 system with valid certificates

Comment: The following code works on Ubu ntu 12.04 but not on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: So you have a valid certificate on the server that the client can verify against either a provided CA, or is included in Ubuntu's standard CA list?

Comment: We did not include any certificates in Ubuntu 16.04 standard CA list

Comment: Do you have a self signed certificate? Where does the certificate come from? What have you done to make the client able to verify the certificate? Certificate validation fails, which is why I am asking about the properties of the certificate.

Comment: We don't have a self-signed certificate. We did not change anything for certificates in Ubuntu 16.04, We just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and run the following python code

Comment: What I have to do in Ubuntu 16.04 for certificates?

Comment: so what certificate do you have? What happens if you go to the server address with a web browser? What's the properties of the certificate?

Comment: We have default certificates

Comment: Please include the output of `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 192.168.0.*:443` in your question. This will give information about the certificate. Obviously, you will have to insert the real IP...

Comment: @Vidrlo following is the output of openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 192.168.0.*:443

Comment: In answer section I have added output.

Comment: [Edit] your question to add information, do ***not*** answer unless you **actually** answer your question.

Comment: Hello Vidarlo... Can you please give me an example to Encrypt, or configure a working PKI structure within my company (using EasyRSA.) Without installing the apache on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 6):

Try running the below commands:

```
$ sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
$ export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
```

Comment: This is still relevant with Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your certificate is expired according to the output you provided. Furthermore, it has some dubious entries in the Organization field, so I would guess it's self signed as well...

Get a new, valid certificate from for instance Let's Encrypt, or configure a working PKI structure within your company, for instance using EasyRSA.